# Plotting the free vibration response of a single degree of freedom graph in matlab

Tags: matlab

As part of the assignment, we have to plot the free vibration response of a single degree of freedom graph over the displacement vs time. The t should increase up to 3 seconds with the increment of the .05. When I try to plot the graph based on the code below I am not getting any graphs at all. Please any help would be highly appreciated. Please let me know if need to provide more information.

```
% Main subroutine to generate the response of a SDOF
z = 0.05;
w = 2*pi;
dt = 0.05; % dt represent the change in time which is constant
Tmax = 3;
TN = 1.0;
i = 0; % number of time step starting with 0
x = 0; % initial position
v = 0; % velocity at start time and position
x_vector = [x; v]; 
t = [0:0.05:3]; % defining the time vector 0 to 3 seconds
t_i = t;
% Insert the DHMAT scripts for calculating the matrix A and B
w_d = w*sqrt(1-z.^2);
DHMAT;

% Start the loop

for t_i = [0:dt:Tmax]
    % Insert the EXCIT script to calculate the excitation (f_vector)
    f = EXIT(t, dt);
    f_vector =[1;1];
    i = i+1;
    x_vectornew = A*x_vector - B*f_vector;
    % t_i = t_i + dt;
end
plot(t_i, x_vectornew);
```

Comment: I have transcribed the code (approval pending), but next time please don't attach an image of the code. Instead, insert the code as text. Possibly check my transcription...

Comment: As it stands, we can't run this code. We have no idea what DHMAT and EXIT are. This makes it quite difficult to debug the code. My guess would be that it is crashing before you get to your plot command - maybe step through and check this?

Comment: DHMT and EXCIT file are the subroutine file to calculate the A and B matrixes and the x_vector

Comment: Okay, but we don't know what they do, and if there's anything wrong in DHMT or EXIT, then we can't tell

Comment: Looking at your code again: `f_vector` and `x_vector` don't seem to change at each loop iteration, unless EXIT does something, and so you will get a non-changing result. Additionally, after your loop has finished you try to plot only the most recent value of `x_vectornew`, which has dimensions 2x1, against t_i which has dimensions 1x1.